# How to improve the speed of a Joomla site launched at Server2Go

Tags: mysql

I created a website with Joomla 1.5 and i am using Server2Go as my local server and this site will be used for presentation purposes in a CD.

So, this site is about to 500 MB with its database included and it has installed joomfish and phocagallery components. 
In addition, this site contains articles with many photos inserted with hign analysis.It is for presenting an island,so the pictures should have high analysis.

I burned all this to a Cd-Rom with Power-ISO and Server2Go inside and working fine but i have problem with the loading time and the navigation time between menu item.

The PROBLEM is that It takes more than 15 seconds to load!

Any suggestions or ideas about improving this whole concept will be appreciated very much.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As it's not a dynamic site that will work in a server environment you could enable full joomla caching using:

```
Global Configuration -> Cache Settings -> ON - Conservative caching
Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> System - Cache (enable)
```

Before you create the cd please try to open all pages in order to have all the content cached.

Good Luck!

Comment: Good one ! Can you help me more please? Maybe if you know aout MySQL optimization or Server2Go configuration.I will wait thanks

Comment: I am sorry I have never used server2go before. Using the above trick you will be sure that joomla would have the best possible speed as it would run fully cached. Please check also if your template has an option for Css and Js caching.